# Calculating customer retention between months SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I need to calculate the customer retention between months. My table is as such

| year_month | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05 | abc |
| 2022-05 | asd |
| 2022-05 | xyz |
| 2022-06 | abc |
| 2022-06 | xyz |
| 2022-06 | qwe |
| 2022-07 | abc |
| 2022-07 | asd |

I need to get an output such that if a customer id showed up in both the current and previous month, then they will be considered as a retained customer.
For instance, as abc and xyz are in both 2022-05 and 2022-06, thus there were 2 customers retained in 2022-06. asd is not included in retention as it does not appear in **consecutive months**.

Below is an example of the output.

Expected output:

| year_month | customers_retained |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06 | 2 |
| 2022-07 | 1 |

Comment: INNER JOIN by the same user and 1 month difference then GROUP BY and COUNT.

Comment: @Akina hi Akina, thanks for your reply! I'm not sure how to do the 1 month difference as I am rather new to SQL

Comment: Define retention properly. "asd" appears twice.

Comment: @PChemGuy the customer would have to appear in consecutive months - asd is not included in retention as they do not appear in 2022-06

Comment: *I'm not sure how to do the 1 month difference* Add 1 month to one value then compare it with another value.

Comment: @Akina sure but what's the code for it?

Comment: Your values are not date ones. So simply parse them to components then work with `year * 12 + month`. Or backward, concatenate `'-01'` then work with them like they're dates.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the date first, then do self join and group by date. See the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8odpZ7NsemJSQQkjojdKPb/0)

```sql
WITH
    data_ex AS (
        SELECT
            substr(year_month, 1, 4) * 12 + substr(year_month, 6, 2) AS month,
            year_month,
            customer_id
        FROM data
    )
SELECT data_ex.year_month, sum(prev.customer_id IS NOT NULL) AS retained
FROM data_ex, data_ex AS prev
WHERE data_ex.month = prev.month + 1 AND data_ex.customer_id = prev.customer_id
GROUP BY data_ex.month;
```